# How to configure launch.json for NextJs and Typesctipt

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, vscode-debugger, ts-node

I am trying to create a launch.json file for the following repo:

https://github.com/zakariamofaddel/shopify-nextjs-template

I have tried both the default VS Code node template and the [NextJs launch file](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging).

**VS code default Node generated .vscode/launch.json file**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\server\\index.ts"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to run yarn dev successfully and use console.log:

https://github.com/zakariamofaddel/shopify-nextjs-template/blob/38c700d8706818aa12d892b3f1193a969919e003/package.json#L9

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after adding the TypeScript Debugger extension in VS code.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Localhost",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}\\server\\server.ts"
            ],
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-r",
                "ts-node/register/transpile-only"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```